# Saving dynamic form field data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I Have a for where you can add multiple lines by click on a button and I want to store the data into the database

This is the error I get when I submit the form - Array to string conversion

form inputs I didn't post the form element since I don't think I needed to show it here

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer[]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="produce[]" />
<select class="form-control" name="task[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pick Up">Pick Up</option>
    <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="units[]" />
```

controller code

```
public function createManifest(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           // validate hidden
           'date_val'       => 'required',
           'driver_name'    => 'required',
           'truck_num'      => 'required',
           'run_num'        => 'required',
           // validate fields
           'customer'       => 'required',
           'produce'        => 'required',
           'task'           => 'required',
           'units'          => 'required',
        ]);

        $manifest = new Manifest([
           'user_id'        => Auth::user()->id,
           'date'           => $request->input('date_val'),
           'driver_name'    => $request->input('driver_name'),
           'truck_number'   => $request->input('truck_num'),
           'run_number'     => $request->input('run_num'),
           'customer_name'  => $request->input('customer'),
           'produce'        => $request->input('produce'),
           'task'           => $request->input('task'),
           'units'          => $request->input('units'),
        ]);

        $manifest->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database columns where you try to store those lists of values are strings and you're passing an array to the Manifest's constructor, hence the error.

In order to fix it, you need to tell Laravel that those values will be arrays so that it can do necessary conversion between array and string - it encodes it as JSON internally.

You need to add the following in your model:

```
protected $casts = [
  'customer' => 'array',
  'produce' => 'array',
  'task' => 'array',
  'units' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: Hey, I have some more questions about displaying the data is there any place we can chat?

Comment: You can post another question, I’m sure someone here will help :) Or even me, just later 